# MailAddress: An invalid character was found in the mail header

Tags: c#, .net, email, exception, mailaddress

I am using MailAddress to create a fax email.
We are using system called SatisFAXtion v 8.6.
To provide a cover page for faxing I can add a template location to the mail.TO address.

The format looks like this:

```
12125551234^template=cp\\FAXReportCover.rtf@fax.ourcompanymail.com
```

When compiling it works fine but I need two backslashes so I added two more as escape characters.

When I run the program I get an exception:

```
Message: An invalid character was found in the mail header:
StackTrace: at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseLocalPart(String data, Int32& index, Boolean expectAngleBracket, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseMultipleAddresses(String data)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.ParseValue(String addresses)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.Add(String addresses)
   at System.Net.Mail.Message..ctor(String from, String to)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor(String from, String to)
```

Is there a way to insert backslashes in an email address in MailAddress object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part):

> The restrictions for special characters are that they must only be
>   used *when contained between quotation marks*, and that 3 of them (The
>   space, backslash \ and quotation mark " (ASCII: 32, 92, 34)) must also
>   be preceded by a backslash \ (e.g. "\ \\"").

Therefore, I don't think your email address is valid as the backslashes are not contained between quotation marks.

If you could change the address to something like `12125551234^template="cp\\"FAXReportCover.rtf@fax.ourcompanymail.com` I think it would be ok.

Comment: So this has fixed the problem, but just had to put the full address in quotes:

Comment: `"\"12125551234^template=cp\\\\FAXReportCover.rtf\"" + "@fax.ourcompanymail.com"`

Answer (score 3):

Years ago I found a workaround over a similar issue. The issue was in the DisplayName parameter in the constructor of MailAddress.

Maybe it will help you too:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/09/smtpclient-exception-invalid-character.html

Comment: Beware, your workaround is for the displayName parameter, not the address parameters.

Comment: I have removed the downvotes and improved the answers instead. Although they do not address the exact problem of the question they may be useful to future users.

Comment: To make it a better answer, please include the solution, not just a link to another website.

Comment: @xpereta: This is not just a website, it's my blog. Anyway, thanks for the insight and the correction.

Comment: I know it's your blog and you care about it, but for future users it's an external website. The answer here should contain the explanation to  solve the question if possible.

Comment: @xpereta: true. I woudn't even comment if this was a fresh question. However, it's a year and a half old, the OP didn't give any feedback on that and frankly, I forgot about it, just as I forgot dozens of other answers I provide and there is no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when  if this is modified to "network" --- then error got resolved. ( My understanding is - Incase of specified pickupdirectory option, the header -encoding utf-8 (base64) was giving error )

Hope it helps